# How to create basic line chart (HightCharts) from HTML table data?

Tags: html, highcharts, html-table

I want to know can we create line chart with highcharts and  data can be extracted from HTML table? I am new and I have searched out but I did not get any help as per need. So if anyone knows then please kindly provide me links or sample/example.

Comment: And an example of your table from which you wish to extract the data to display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HighCharts demo gallery has an example of this [here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-parsed). And this is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-parsed/). Just change the `type` of chart from `'column'` to `'line'`:

```
...
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line'
            },
...
```